# Implement Push notification in Android Phonegap app

Tags: ionic-framework, phonegap-build, phonegap-pushplugin

Created UI using Angular and Ionic, and wrapper usign Phonegap, How can I have pushnotification in Android implemented.
Is there any effective and accurate library in Phonegap for Pushnotification Implemented.

Already using https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin, but getting some issues, like push notififcation not received, some time all notification coming at once.

Answer (score 2):

1. First create a project in Google console
2. Enable GCM
3. Create a server api Key

use the following plugin

```
cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="XXXXXXX"
```

replace the xxxxxx with your sender id

n your javascript add the following code for registering to GCM server it will give you a GCM id

```
   var push = PushNotification.init({
android: {
    senderID: "XXXXXXXX" //add your sender id here
},
ios: {
    alert: "true",
    badge: "true",
    sound: "true"
},
windows: {}
});

push.on('registration', function(data) {   
    consol.log(data.registrationId);  //this function give registration id from the GCM server if you dont want to see it please comment it
    document.getElementById("gcm_id").value= data.registrationId; //showing registration id in our app. If it shows our registration process is suscess
    //$("#gcm_id").val(data.registrationId);  if you are using jquery
});
```

Send a message using GCM HTTP connection server protocol:

```
https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send

Content-Type:application/json
  Authorization:key=YOUR SERVER KEY
  {
    "to": "GCM ID",
    "data": {
      "message": "This is a GCM Topic Message!",
     }
  }
```

for more details..

http://phonegaptut.com/2016/05/31/how-to-send-push-notifications-in-phonegap-application/

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem lately, using Ionic and Cordova (not Phonegap, but should work the same).
I ended up using this library for local push notifications https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-localNotifications

They worked pretty well except the PN would not start the app on Android, but I [opened a pull request with a fix for that](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-localNotifications/pull/34).
If you encounter the same problem, you might also use [my fork](https://github.com/tmaximini/phonegap-plugin-localNotifications) of this plugin which has this fix already included.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [ngCordova's Push Plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/) for this.

From the docs:

> Allows your application to receive push notifications. To receive notifications in your controllers or services, listen for pushNotificationReceived event.

Answer (score 1):

As Push Notification is a native feature, so to integrate Push in PhoneGap Android application you have to make a plugin that will communicate with Android Native code.

You can go through with [Sample application](https://github.com/VishnuGShephertz/Android-Push-Notification-in-PhoneGap-application) available on Git Hub.
Please also follow the necessary steps require for it mentioned in ReadME file.